The model provided by UNSLOTH cannot be downloaded in the WSL environment
error:
MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/models/unsloth/Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-bnb-4bit/commits/main?p=1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4d9e49bed0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))"), '(Request ID: c60c5b88-b505-4258-864c-04cb2d960132)')
code:
model, tokenizer = FastLanguageModel.from_pretrained("unsloth/Meta-Llama-3.1-8B", max_seq_length=max_seq_length, dtype=dtype, load_in_4bit=load_in_4bit)

set proxy and run successfully this code：curl www.google.com
set image net and download other model succeed:
import os os.environ["HF_ENDPOINT"] = "https://hf-mirror.com" from transformers import AutoTokenizer tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-chinese")


try using curl to check connectivity to huggingface.co. You can visit google.com doesn't mean you can also visit huggingface.co. If you find the curl command fails, you need to add huggingface.co to your proxy configuration  file. so your proxy software will proxy requests to huggingface.co.
